# Makefile Combining Object Creation With Linking

Tags: windows, makefile, googletest

I am trying to follow and convert [this][1] Googletest tutorial to work in windows and use Make for building. I am also trying to add a more typical directory structure.
[1]: https://www.eriksmistad.no/getting-started-with-google-test-on-ubuntu/

My directory structure:

```
D:.
│   makefile
│
├───bin
├───inc
│       whattotest.h
│
├───obj
├───src
│       whattotest.cpp
│
└───tests
        tests.cpp
```

whattotest.h

```
#pragma once

double squareRoot(const double a);
```

whattotest.cpp

```
#include <math.h>
#include "whattotest.h"
 
double squareRoot(const double a) {
    double b = sqrt(a);
    if(b != b) { // nan check
        return -1.0;
    }else{
        return sqrt(a);
    }
}
```

tests.cpp

```
#include "whattotest.h"
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
 
TEST(SquareRootTest, PositiveNos) { 
    ASSERT_EQ(6, squareRoot(36.0));
    ASSERT_EQ(18.0, squareRoot(324.0));
    ASSERT_EQ(25.4, squareRoot(645.16));
    ASSERT_EQ(0, squareRoot(0.0));
}
 
TEST(SquareRootTest, NegativeNos) {
    ASSERT_EQ(-1.0, squareRoot(-15.0));
    ASSERT_EQ(-1.0, squareRoot(-0.2));
}
 
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

makefile

```
CXX = g++
OBJ = obj
SRC = src
TESTS = tests
INC = inc
BIN = bin
LIBS= -lpthread
GTEST=D:\myWorkspace\Gtest\googletest-release-1.11.0\googletest\include\
LIBGTEST=D:\myWorkspace\Gtest\googletest-release-1.11.0\lib\libgtest.a

.PHONY : all
all: $(BIN)/runTests

$(BIN)/runTests: $(OBJ)/tests.o $(OBJ)/whattotest.o $(LIBGTEST)
    #g++ -o runTests obj/tests.o obj/whattotest.o <path to libgtest.a> -pthread
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)
    
$(OBJ)/tests.o: $(TESTS)/tests.cpp
    #g++ -I <path to gtest> -I inc -c tests.cpp -o tests.o
    $(CXX) -I $(GTEST) -I $(INC) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJ)/whattotest.o: $(SRC)/whattotest.cpp
    $(CXX) -I $(INC) -c $< -o $@
    
clean:
    -rm $(OBJ)/*.o
    -rm $(BIN)/*.exe
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
g++ -I D:\myWorkspace\Gtest\googletest-release-1.11.0\googletest\include LIBGTEST=D:\myWorkspace\Gtest\googletest-release-1.11.0\lib\libgtest.a -I inc -c tests/tests.cpp -o obj/tests.o
g++: warning: LIBGTEST=D:\myWorkspace\Gtest\googletest-release-1.11.0\lib\libgtest.a: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++: error: LIBGTEST=D:\myWorkspace\Gtest\googletest-release-1.11.0\lib\libgtest.a: linker input file not found: Invalid argument
make: *** [makefile:19: obj/tests.o] Error 1
```

The way I thought this would run would be for Make to see the Rule for runTests requires tests.o, which does not exist, then drop down and use the Rule for creating that object file. After that, return to the Rule for runTests and complete.

The output looks like Make is combining the two rules together into some kind of amalgamation with -c and .cpp files combined. Which I believe is causing this error to occur.

I am confused as to why Make is doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```
GTEST=D:\myWorkspace\Gtest\googletest-release-1.11.0\googletest\include\
LIBGTEST=D:\myWorkspace\Gtest\googletest-release-1.11.0\lib\libgtest.a
```

By having a backslash at the end of the `GTEST` variable assignment you've continued that line to the next line, so `GTEST` contains the variable assignment on the next line as well (and `LIBGTEST` is not set).

You've basically written this:

```
GTEST=D:\myWorkspace\Gtest\googletest-release-1.11.0\googletest\include LIBGTEST=D:\myWorkspace\Gtest\googletest-release-1.11.0\lib\libgtest.a
```

You should not, in general, use backslashes in makefiles.  You should use forward slashes for directory separators.

If you do want to use backslashes at the least you should not add them at the end of variable assignments.

Comment: That did the trick. I also forgot to add a rule to build whattotest.o for anyone else wanting to use the tutorial.